# Exec php under nginx fastcgi

Tags: php, macos, nginx, environment-variables, homebrew

Env:

- macOs/Debian/Ubuntu
- Nginx and Php(installed by Brew on macOs)

Script example:

```php
<?php

var_dump(exec("php -v"));
```

Result:

- macOs: `php unknown command`
- Debian/Ubuntu: return info about php version

If get info about `ENV`(`exec("ENV")`) on macOs from web-browser(processed nginx)- no info about `PATH` variable, on terminal - regular `PATH` info(ofc cze it terminal's execution)

How to pass adequate `ENV` data to php-script which execute under fpm?

Answer (score 0):

Your example script is attempting to execute the CLI PHP using whatever PHP is connected to your webserver (most likely PHP-FPM). The latter is working but the former is not. It could be a path issue, it might be that the CLI SAPI is not installed. Given the massive performance overhead, there are only downsides to calling the CLI PHP from web PHP, but it is possible that there may be other OS commands you should be accessing from PHP. A better way to test what environment variables are presented to PHP would be `print_r $_ENV;`

If you want environment variables in PHP then configure them in your webserver or in the FPM pool config (or whatever startsup FPM and add `clear_env = no` to the pool config)